# Spring MVC: HTTP 400 Error when trying to upload csv files

Tags: java, spring, file, jsp, spring-mvc

**Problem**: I am following this guide to upload files via Spring MVC: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ However when I do so, I keep getting the following error when I upload a file via the form on my .jsp page:

> HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'name' is not present
>
> type Status report
>
> message Required String parameter 'name' is not present
>
> description The request sent by the client was syntactically
>   incorrect.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.52

**Question**: How do I resolve the 400 error and upload the file successfully?

**Approach**: Through following the guide, I have created a controller class, TestController, and a method called handleFileUpload, which is what deals with the user uploading a file. I stayed away from using the multipartResolver bean as it gave me all sorts of errors related to Apache Commons found in a previous question I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467250/unable-to-upload-a-file-using-spring-apache-commons-issue

**Code**

TestController.java

```
    @Controller
    public class TestController {

       @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
       public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
      }


    }
```

Here is the form within index.jsp. Keep in mind I am using TWBS within my jsp pages, I am not sure if that would make any huge difference in this.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br/>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/><br/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

---

**Update 2.22.16**
Orest's comment was helpful, however when I do follow link (http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-single-multiple-file-upload-example-with-tomcat) I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
```

A note to add as to why I receive the above error: whenever I add the following bean to my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file, the above error is given when I try to upload a file: `<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />`

---

**Update #2 2.22.16**
oshi would like to know if the correct jar is in my classpath. I am using IntelliJ and it is in my External Libraries folder. Please view the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Anyways you should configure multipartResolver. You could try this tutorial for example http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-single-multiple-file-upload-example-with-tomcat

Comment: @Orest thanks for posting that, it did help however as I configure multiPartResolver, I run into the same issue I have linked in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467250/unable-to-upload-a-file-using-spring-apache-commons-issue?lq=1

I have updated this question for further review.

Comment: Can you confirm you have the correct jar file in your application's classpath?

Comment: @ochi confirmed, please view the screenshot above. I have the jar in my external libraries folder. To my understanding, this should be enough?

Comment: No, it's not enough.  External libraries are good for dev, compiling but they are not good if they are not included in your classpath at run time - check what's included in your artifact by going into the 'edit configurations' panel

Comment: @ochi you are correct! That resolved my issue :) Thank you! I went into my Project Structure > Artifacts, and simply deleted and added my war artifacts again. It worked perfectly. The edit configurations panel didn't get to show me my artifacts, though. Is that an issue on my end which could hurt me later on down the road in dev?

Also if you would like, you can paste your comment as an answer so you get the points.

Comment: It's not an issue but yes, for down the road, you need to be aware that all the necessary jar files are included in the web-app you are going to deploy.  Sometimes, if the same jar file is in multiple web-apps, you can add them to the server's lib folder (so only one copy of the jar file, shared by all apps, is necessary). There are pros/cons with this approach (too long for this comment) but you need to be aware of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include all the necessary `.jar` files in your application's `classpath`.

By the error, it sounds like the jar file was not found at runtime.

In other words, all your necessary external libraries (which you use for dev, compiling) need to be included in your classpath at run time as well.

In IntelliJ you can check what's included in your artifact by going into the 'Project Structure > Artifacts' panel.

I am not an Eclipse user but there are ways of verifying so there as well.